# automatically "killTimer" when script is manually terminated using the VBE "reset" button

Tags: vba

After I set a timer with SetTimer (lib "user32"), it must be killed with KillTimer before ending the script, otherwise it causes weird behaviors like closing the intellisense menu every time the (ghost) timer fires.

However, some times when in an emergency situation I must stop the script via the "reset" button of the VBE and this causes the timer to remain unkilled, with the consequent weird behaviours.

Is there a way to automatically run a KillTimer when I press the "reset" button?

[image]

Comment: What you have in mind talking by a "reset" but? Working with an API timer involves a very good error handling. This means that all possible errors should be trapped and guide to a code part killing it. Theoretically, you can imagine a "reset" button creating a public `Boolean` variable at module level and inserting in the timer loop procedure something like `If boolVar then  KillTimer 0&, TimerID`. Where `TimerID` to also be a `Public` variable obtained as `TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, ...`. A `DoEvents` line should also be necessary. Then, make `boolVar = True` in a Sub called by a "reset" butt

Comment: When asking such a question, the code showing us how you use it should be a must, in my opinion... You can simpler receive suggestion to modify something, than explaining theories in words.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the "reset" button of the VBE, that leaves the timer alive

Comment: The reset button is a full-stop to the entire VB Project. All event scripts are terminated. I would be astonished if anyone was able to create an event hook off of a button that terminates events. That being said, I love being surprised, so I hope to be proven wrong.

Comment: SetTimer is external to the project/Excel, so the timer continues to call my TimerTick procedure forever even after I press the "reset" button.
If I add a  debug.print "surprise me" in the TimerTick procedure, I see it continually written in the immediate window, forever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer continues in the application, separate from any single VB Project. But event scripts must be part of a VB Project. If you press the reset button, I don't imagine that it will be able to trigger an event script in the project that was just reset.

Instead, you can use the timer's script to track the project session and check to see if the session has been reset.

Here's a simplified example, using `Application.OnTime` instead of `SetTimer`:

```vb
Dim eventTime As Date
Sub StartTimer()
    timer start:=True
End Sub

Sub timer(Optional start As Boolean = False)
    If eventTime = 0 And Not start Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print Now
    eventTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    Application.OnTime eventTime, "Module1.Timer"
End Sub
```

The `OnTime` loop continues even if you press the Reset Button, but the reset button clears the value in `eventTime` so the next time the timer script runs, `eventTime = 0` is true and the `OnTime` loop is exited.

Comment: KillTimer requires the TimerID (returned by SetTimer) to be able to kill the timer. I should find a way to retrieve the TimerID even after the "reset".

Comment: @6diegodiego9 You can use an external file, or a worksheet cell to save the value independently of the VB Project session.

Comment: My final solution was to store the TimerID variable outside the VBA environment with "Activeworksheet.Names.Add Name:="TimerID", RefersTo:=TimerID, Visible:=False" and kill it with KillTimer 0, Replace(wks.Names("TimerID"), "=", "")